# How to bind the tag p in template?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template

Problem: The `<p>` element does not work. (Angular parser fails to render the tag **p**)
In [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) document from official tutorial, this code snippet works fine:

```
...
template: `
        <div>
            <ul>
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>`
...
```

But this code does not work:

```
...
template: `
        <p>
            <ul>
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </p>`
...
```

Error in **FireBug** is as follow:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "p" ("
              <li>2</li>
            </ul>
          [ERROR ->]</p>
        </div>"): AppComponent@14:14
```

Can someone explain why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `<p>` element doesn't support `<ul>` as content https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Event though browsers might not complain and display it anyway, it is not valid HTML and the Angular2 parser is strict.

Comment: Eagle eyes +1, hoping you will reach to 100k today itself :)

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks, but I guess I have to wait 1 or 2 days more :-[ :D